# Error with batch submit in R

Tags: linux, r, batch-file

I am trying to submit R in batch on Linux, but usually 30-40 minutes after the submit, the process stops and I get the message below. The message appears in the .Rout file, not the Linux shell. To submit I use **R CMD BATCH myprogram.R &**

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'CxException'
  what():
```

The program works without problems when submitted from within R itself, but for some reason it stops midway through the execution when submitted in batch. *The process stops while creating a 45000 x 10000 matrix*

Here is an overview of the program. It starts by reading three files from CSV. Next, it creates a 45000 x 10000 matrix which takes up about 3.7GB of RAM. The matrix is a document-term matrix, in which 1 is assigned when a term is in a doc, 0 otherwise. Then it goes through a few more steps in which that matrix is used to produce the results. At that point the RAM increases to about 4.5GB and it stays at that level. I monitor the job in Linux, and it seems that there are enough free resources, both CPU and RAM, for the rest of the processes to run.

Any ideas/suggestions what may be causing it?

**Added clarification:**
1) The R version is Revolution R v.6.2;  2) No additional packages are being used;

Comment: Is your algorithm deterministic (nothing random?) Any idea what function is being called as it throws the error? What packages are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You might have better luck using `Rscript.exe` rather then `R CMD BATCH`.

The syntax you would want to use for that is:

`"%PATH TO EXE%\Rscript.exe" "%PATH TO SCRIPT%\script.R" "INPUT ARGUMENTS (if any)"`

Comment: Hi, I tried it, but with the same result as R CMD BATCH. The process stops and I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

It is something which Rev-R should fix it. However, you can execute your code using source function within R session.
The Syntax is:

```
R -e 'source("Your_Script.R")'
```